# Getting Enviroment Variable with cpp

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, environment-variables

So I have been trying to figure out how to find an environment variable and print it out on the screen in c++
but for the last 3 hours or so, I have been stuck. When I print out the currentDesktop variable it only prints out "/Desktop". But what I'm looking for is the username in front of it.
I have been reading the documentation on the GetEnviromentVariable function from Microsoft's forum and this is what I have come up with so far.
Help would be greatly appreciated since I'm not so experienced yet, Thx.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#define BUFSIZE 4096
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    LPCWSTR Env = L"%USERPROFILE";
    LPTSTR pszOldVal;
    string IPADD;
     pszOldVal = (LPTSTR)malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof(TCHAR));
    if (NULL == pszOldVal)
    {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    string currentDesktop = GetEnvironmentVariable(Env,pszOldVal,BUFSIZE) + "\\Desktop";
    cout << currentDesktop;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The documentation of [std::getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) has an easy to follow example.

Comment: If you want the user, why not use `%USERPROFILE%`?

Comment: @CPPNEWBIE reread your code carefully. What it contains, not what you think it does.

Comment: Aha, you forgot to convert `GetEnvironmentVariable(Env,pszOldVal,BUFSIZE)` into a `std::string` before you added `"\\Desktop"` to the returned results.  `GetEnvironmentVariable` returns a `char*`, not a `std::string`

Comment: @NathanOliver "*`GetEnvironmentVariable` returns a `char*`*" - no, it *takes* a `char[]` and *returns* a `DWORD` specifying how many characters were copied into the `char[]`. You are thinking of `(std::)getenv()` instead.

Comment: @fra `std::getenv` is useless on Windows. You'd have to go with the Microsoft-specific extension [_wgetenv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv) to get to a base level of reliability. Neither one is part of the solution to the *actual* problem the OP is trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the [`GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable) function.  For one thing, you are missing the trailing `%` on the variable name `L"%USERPROFILE"`. For another thing, the return value is the number of characters copied into the supplied buffer.  You are adding that integer to the string literal `"\\Desktop"`, which is not what you want.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

std::wstring GetEnv(const std::wstring &varName)
{
    std::wstring str;
    DWORD len = GetEnvironmentVariableW(varName.c_str(), NULL, 0);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        str.resize(len);
        str.resize(GetEnvironmentVariableW(varName.c_str(), &str[0], len));
    }
    return str;
}

std::wstring GetUserDesktopPath()
{
    std::wstring path = GetEnv(L"%USERPROFILE%");
    if (!path.empty()) path += L"\\Desktop";
    return path;
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring currentDesktop = GetUserDesktopPath();
    std::wcout << currentDesktop;
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, if you just want the username, use `%USERNAME%` instead of `%USERPROFILE%`.  Or better, use [`GetUserName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamew) instead of `GetEnvironmentVariable()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

std::wstring GetUserName()
{
    std::wstring str;
    DWORD len = 0;
    if (!GetUserNameW(NULL, &len))
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            str.resize(len);
            if (GetUserNameW(&str[0], &len))
                str.resize(len-1);
            else
                str = L"";
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring currentUser = GetUserName();
    std::wcout << currentUser;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the *correct* way to get the path to the user's desktop is to just ask Windows for that specific path, don't *assume* it is in the root of the user's profile, or that is is named `Desktop`.  Use [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) for that query, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

std::wstring GetFolderPath(CSIDL folderID)
{
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {};
    SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, folderID, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, path);
    return path;
}
/* or:
std::wstring GetFolderPath(REFKNOWNFOLDERID folderID)
{
    std::wstring str;
    PWSTR path = NULL;
    if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(folderID, 0, NULL, &path) == S_OK)
        str = path;
    CoTaskMemFree(path);
    return str;
}
*/

std::wstring GetUserDesktopPath()
{
    return GetFolderPath(CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY);
    // or: return GetFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop);
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring currentDesktop = GetUserDesktopPath();
    std::wcout << currentDesktop;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When testing the Shlobj header I got a couple of errors. specifically when using the GetFolderPath(CSIDL_DESKTOP, FOLDERID_Desktop). The error says "no instance of constructor". What does this mean?

Comment: @CPPNEWBIE Please provide the *exact* error message verbatim, and indicate which line of code the error is referring to.

Comment: Linkage specification is incompatible with previous "SHGetKnownFolderPath"(declared at line 1046 of "C:/blah/blah/blaH/shlobj_core.h"

Comment: I tried using the SHGETKNOWNFOLDERPATH() instead. Got that error 
this is way out of my league, and i have no idea what im doing at this point.

Comment: @CPPNEWBIE Well, now you are quoting a completely different error. What happened to the constructor error you first mentioned? You are making this difficult to help you.